# How to retrieve value of pwd from powershell in c# code

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dotnet-tool

I was looking for the answer at least 3 hours, but without success.
Everywhere are just pieces of code and I have no idea how to connect them together.

What I want to achieve:
I am creating dotnet-tool in which I need to process current working directory (value which is printed using `pwd` command in PS).
Dotnet tool will be installed in default directory C:\Users\Samuel\.dotnet\.store\myTool... but command can be invoked in any directory in PS using `dotnet tool run myTool`.

For example:
In PS I am in: C:\Users\Samuel\AxisRepos> and I run `dotnet tool run myTool`
In this case I want to retrieve C:\Users\Samuel\AxisRepos in C# code to find out, in which directory command was invoked.

So simply put, I want to do something like this in my dotnet tool:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pwd = GetPwdFromPowerShell();
    }

    static string GetPwdFromPowerShell()
    {
        string pwd = "";

        // Retrieve current working directory from PS in which dotnet tool was invoked

        return pwd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pwd` is just an alias for `Get-Location` which shows the current directory...

From c# you can use the built-in .net class `System.IO.Directory` specifically the method `GetCurrentDirectory`

So just update your code to:

```
static string GetPwd()
{
    return System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
}
```

And from powershell this will have the same results:

```
[System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
```

Comment: I already tried this one and it returns root directory to place where assembly of my project lives.
So it does not work. I need directory from which dotnet tool which invokes c# code was called.

Comment: Okey, I found out that this method behaves differently in debug and release. In debug it returns root directory to place where assembly lives. In release it returns working directory in PS from which my tool was invoked.